# Ubuntu and Logitech USB external speaker

Tags: usb, sound, logitech

[image: Second Sound Screenshot]My desktop has a cheap pair of USB logitech external speakers.  I've just downloaded Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and the speakers no longer work.  My sound comes from an Intel chipset on the motherboard, and I am getting sound through audio jack to my monitor speakers, but even with the Ubuntu sound and the monitor sound control at maximum, I can barely hear it.  I'm older and getting a bit deaf.

I have tested the sound and I'm not getting line out sound, although the monitor does have a separate attachment through the sound jack.  My sound is coming through through the HDMI/Display Port 2--GF119 HDMI Audio Controller.

[Screenshot of lsusb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42LuH.png)

I have set the Ubuntu System Control for sound to more than 100% and have achieved audible sound.

Can I revive the USB Logitech speakers which did work for me on Windows XP, or should I just put them on the shelf?

Screenshot from sound:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the available sound devices in System Settings?

Comment: How do I do that?  I've taken and saved the screenshot and also asked to copy to clipboard, but when the menu for this box doesn't allow paste.  Control-V doesn't work either.

Comment: There's an image button in the menu bar of the editor.

Comment: And where do I find that menu bar of the editor?  I can't seem to find anything in or around the box for posts.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Settings/Sound, and change the "Play sound through" settings so that the output goes to your Logitech USB speakers.

[image]

**Update #1:**

We needed to...

- plug in the speaker's USB cable (sigh)
- change the BIOS to enable legacy USB mode

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58267/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-ubuntu-and-logitech-usb-external-speaker).

Answer (score -1):

My Logitech USB speakers weren't recognised by the latest Ubuntu, but worked as soon as I plugged into the front headphone jack.  Sounds good now.